# How to avoid people from using the coffee spoon into the sugar jar?

Tags: physical

Do you have any creative ideas how to avoid people using the coffee spoon into the sugar jar?
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Buy a sugar shaker. Then people can't leave the spoon in it.

Comment: The problem is that people don't see a reference of where to put it back once they use it, mostly because they feel that once they are wet with coffee, they don't belong in their original position. the solution:

Put two or more (coffee used) spoons laid out face down on a plate under the sugar jar. Every user only uses one spoon at a time, and every time they are done using it, they will feel inclined to put them next to the other spoons.